# Integral of $f(x)f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I found a problem that says:

Let $f$ be a real function with continuous derivative on $[a , b]$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Suppose $\int_a^b f(x)^2 dx =1$. Show that $\int_a^b f(x)f'(x) dx = -\frac{1}{2}$.

The suggested solution was to do integration by parts using $u=f(x)^2$ and $dv=dx$ which leads to
$1=\int_a^b f(x)^2 dx = 2xf(x)^2 |_a^b - \int_a^b 2xf(x)f'(x) dx$. Then since $f(a)=f(b)=0$ that makes the first part go away and we get $1=- \int_a^b 2xf(x)f'(x) dx$ then we can make the conclusion.

But what am I missing? We showed that $\int_a^b xf(x)f'(x) dx = -\frac{1}{2}$ but the problem wanted to show $\int_a^b f(x)f'(x) dx = -\frac{1}{2}$. Was this just a typo?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers. I'm a bit rusty on Calculus, but I just needed to make sure I wasn't going insane!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is wrong. You don't even have to integrate by parts to see that $\int_a^{b} f(x)f'(x)dx=0$: $\int_a^{b} f(x)f'(x)dx=\int_a^{b} \frac d {dx} (\frac 1  2(f(x)^{2}) dx=\frac 1  2(f(x)^{2})|_a^{b}=0-0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was a typo.

Note that $(f^2(x))'=2f(x)f'(x)$. Then $$\int_a^bf(x) f'(x) dx=\frac12 (f^2(b) -f^2(a))=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_a^bf(x)f'(x)dx=\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}udu=\frac12\left[u^2\right]_{f(a)}^{f(b)}=\frac{f^2(b)-f^2(a)}{2}=0$$
because $f(a)=f(b)=0$ so the question is wrong